# Отслеживание координат клика на документе. JavaScript [закрыт]

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо отслеживать, куда кликает пользователь. Т.е. не просто клик по какому-либо элементу - а по всему документу, причём нужно сохранять координаты. Например я кликнул в самый верхний левый угол - функция должна вернуть значения 1:1, или что-то в этом роде.

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

**UPD:**
Решение

```
var coords = {}, i = 0;
$(document).click(function(e){
    coords[i++] = {'x':e.pageX,'y':e.pageY};
    $('body').text( JSON.stringify(coords) );
});
```

Comment: повесьте событие на документ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, [вот таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/YJP7D/).

Comment: Немного переделал ваш пример, но спасибо, всё верно :)
Решение добавлю в текст вопроса.